# Avoid unneeded imports with unit tests

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

The [PyCharm IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/%E2%80%8E) encourages me to write unit tests in the same module as my classes lie. I like the idea of every module being tested automatically as I develop, but what bothers me is that I have additional imports that are only used for these unit tests. I can live with `import unittest`, but consider:

```
from lxml import etree


class Foobar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        schema_root = etree.parse("schema/myschema.xsd")
        schema = etree.XMLSchema(schema_root)
        self.parser = etree.XMLParser(schema=schema)

    def valid(self, filename):
        try:
            etree.parse(filename, self.parser)
            return True
        except etree.XMLSyntaxError:
            return False


import unittest
from io import StringIO


class _FoobarTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty_object_is_valid(self):
        foobar = Foobar()
        self.assertTrue(foobar.valid(StringIO("<object />")))
```

I thought about instead doing it this way:

```
class _FoobarTest(unittest.TestCase):
    from io import StringIO as StringIO_

    def test_empty_object_is_valid(self):
        foobar = Foobar()
        self.assertTrue(foobar.valid(self.StringIO_("<object />")))
```

but that does not feel very natural to me. Since Python is a language that does care about best practice a lot; is there a somewhat official statement on this? I wasn't able to find anything in the PEP documents on this, which made me wonder if it is a good idea to unit test in the same module at all.

Comment: Could you explain in what way PyCharm encourages tests in the same module as classes?

Comment: @zero323 1. they show it in a video on their homepage, 2. the IDE notices if there are unit tests in the module and automatically runs them on several occasions

Comment: IMHO it looks like pretty bad idea. I think [this](http://guide.python-distribute.org/example.html#dos-and-don-ts) could be interesting for you. About PyCharm - you can use auto-test option. Just create run configuration for your tests, perform first run and check `auto-test` button.

Answer (score 1):

Neither PyCharm nor the Python community encourage having unit tests in the same file. [See the PyCharm tutorial on creating unit tests.](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Creating+and+running+a+Python+unit+test) As demonstrated in those instructions, the better way to do unittests is to have them in separate files with a "test_" prefix, which can be discovered and run automatically both by the built in unittest module, or other libraries.

If you look under the [documentation for unittest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) you will find there is already a built-in system for test discovery that works great.

```
python -m unittest discover
```

will find all tests that match the pattern "test*.py" in the current directory. This is the built in default, and best practice until you need something else.